# How to obtain centroidal momentum matrix explicitly for momentum-based control purpose

Tags: drake, rigid-bodies

there are useful APIs to calc centroidal momentum, like `CalcSpatialMomentumInWorldAboutPoint`. But for momentum-based control, I ran into some problems with this API. During control there is:

```
l = A(q) * v
```

and I want to take this as a constraint to solve `vdot` (joint accelerations)

```
l_dot = A(q) * vdot + Adot(q) * v
```

where `l` is the stacked vector of linear and angular momentum, `A(q)` is the centroidal momentum matrix.

My questions are:

1. Is there any method to get the centroidal momentum matrix explicitly?
2. Currently drake use `CalcBiasCenterOfMassTranslationalAcceleration` to get the
   translational part of `Adot(q) * v`, can we get the rotational part too?

@hongkai-dai discussed this at [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10779#issuecomment-675831630), it is also mentioned in other literature [1][2]. Thanks very much for any suggestions.

[1] Koolen, Twan, et al. "Design of a momentum-based control framework and application to the humanoid robot atlas." International Journal of Humanoid Robotics 13.01 (2016): 1650007.
[2] Lee, Sung-Hee, and Ambarish Goswami. "A momentum-based balance controller for humanoid robots on non-level and non-stationary ground." Autonomous Robots 33.4 (2012): 399-414.

Comment: I filed the github issue https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16307 as a feature request.